# VLOOKUP Dilemma multiple matches

Tags: vlookup

ok here is my dilemma; I have a list of colleagues who are getting bonuses that  I have to match with their addresses on another tab; the second tab is a list of all employees and their addresses. I did a VLOOKUP, but I just realized that there are a few employees with the same last name!!! how can I match the addresses (last name is in one column, first in another) to the CORRECT address in the range I named on the second tab?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new column in both tabs.  Concatenate firstname + lastname into the new columns. Use that to do the vlookup.